# How to change color in a theme?

Tags: android, themes

Say I have a color defined in my resources as:

```
<color name="primary_color">#F05B31</color>
```

I then use `@color/primary_color` in a wide variety of styles and view definitions.

Is it possible to programmatically change the color value associated with the resource identifier `primary_color` at run-time to a user-selected color?

Alternatively, is there some other way of globally affecting the primary colors of the application?  I'm aware that I can switch themes somewhat dynamically, but that only allows selection from a predetermined set of themes, and what I'm needing to do is allow selection of an arbitrary palette of colors.

I'm ok with requiring an activity/application restart for the change to take effect.

Comment: resources are read only

Comment: I know that resources are read-only, what I'm looking for may be better stated as a way to address the lookup process that turns primary_color, a resource id, into an actual color, and to affect that lookup process globally through the application.